# can't connect to database server with arduino to send some data

Tags: mysql, database, arduino

I am trying to send some data to my database with Arduino. MariaDB is installed in my PC. Unfortunately, i couldn't connect. My first doubt is server address should be same as my PC ip address? Can someone please help.

```
if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) 
    { Serial.println("Connecting to database server...");
      delay(1000);     
      // Initiate the query class instance
      MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);    
      dtostrf(voltage, 6, 2, voltageNew);
      dtostrf(current, 6, 4, currentNew);     
      sprintf(querymessuremnt, INSERT_measurements,voltageNew, currentNew);

      // Execute the query 
      cur_mem->execute(querybuffer);
      delete cur_mem;
      Serial.println("Data recorded.");
    }
    else   
    Serial.println("Connection to DB failed.");
    conn.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What to add as server name, depends from where you trigger your mentioned code. If you are logged into your Arduino you should use 'localhost' since I assume you are running MariaDB on the Arduino.

If you suspect there are ports problems that prevents your script to fully work, try change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'. If you have a firewall, are you allowing data on port 3306 ?

If you are running the code from another machine but want to access your Arduino/MariaDB, then being on that machine you update your code with server name [ip-adress to your arduino machine].

Comment: From which machine do you trigger the connection code?